# File upload control not working inside update panel

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I am using the following code to upload the file

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel18" runat="server">

   <ContentTemplate>

    <asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="fuImage1" />

    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnUpload1" Text="Upload" 
                               onclick="btnUpload1_Click" />
    <asp:ImageButton ID="btnGetImage1" ImageUrl="images/cam.png" Height="25px" 
                        Width="25px" runat="server" onclick="btnGetImage1_Click" />    
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUpload1" />
    </Triggers> 
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

When i select a file to upload, path is not getting displayed on the file upload control. Need help to fix this problem

Comment: Is anything at all showing in the control where the path should be?

Comment: Nothing is getting displayed in the control after i select the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a frustrating feature of the update panel.  Give this post a read which goes over the cause of this issue as well as a resolution:

http://geekswithblogs.net/mmintoff/archive/2009/04/01/fileupload-within-updatepanel.aspx

Comment: +1 I was never aware of this issue w/ update panels! Great info

Comment: The FileUpload control is within a panel, which is inside another updatePanel . Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: You are seeing this problem because of the UpdatePanel, not the Panel.  Take a look at the link I provided for a description of why it is happening and how to fix it.

Comment: Did everything in that article. The problem i am facing is that nothing is getting displayed in the fileUpload control after i select a file. Is this because of the same reason or something else?

Comment: I would assume it is because of the reasons mentioned in the article.  Have you tried removing the update panel and seeing if it works properly?  Are you using a masterpage?

Comment: Yes, it works fine without update panel . I am using the master page, but only for the navigation bar. Not using any ajax controls in it.

Comment: 404 - File or directory not found.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true" />
    <div>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="conditional">
            <Triggers>
                <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" />
            </Triggers>
            <ContentTemplate>
                 <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
                 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server"Text="Upload" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
```