# How can I prevent a page to be stored in cache during multiple postbacks? Something known as smartnavigation

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, browser-cache

I've an Asp.net .aspx page. I am taking a simple contact us page for example. The page has 3 fields- name/email/question. The scenario is, A user entered a wrong email address, in response, system shows an error message by checking it to a Regex.

Now if user hits back browser button or backspace key, browser displays the same page without error message- that means 1 step behind.

If user does 2 concurrent mistakes- 
1)Leaves name box empty, hits Submit (error message displays says all fields are mandatory).
2)Wrong email, hits Submit (error message displays wrong email entered)

Now if user hits back browser button or backspace key, browser displays the same page with previous error message (for empty box) i.e 1 step behind. Again hits back, displays same page without any error message, i.e 2 steps behind.

I do not want the back button or backspace to do these unwanted actions. I also do not want to disable back button or not to cache anything.

What I need, when user hits back button or backspace, they should be landed to the previously browsed different page, not the same page. That means, I do not want browser cache to hold page during multiple postbacks. Rather, cache should hold page only once when it landed initially.

I heard sometime that this approach called smartnavigation, I tried googling but couldn't find something very useful and optimized. This was the best article I found yet (not sure this is what I am looking for). 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/913721

The problem is, I am not fully sure How to exactly reference this issue.

I hope my question is pretty straight forward (I tried to be clear). Please let me know if something is not clear.

I would greatly appreciate any kind help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you could just put your controls inside an UpdatePanel with UpdateMode set to Always i.e.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
    <ContentTemplate>
        // Your controls
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

You will also need a ScriptManager inside the Form element of the Page e.g.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true" />
....
</form>
```

This will stop the Page doing a full postback and should stop the behaviour you have described. I would also use client side validation with a RegularExpressionValidator or RequiredFieldValidator etc.

Comment: I just tested it and it seemed to work although no postback was being made as I was using a RegularExpressionValidator and a CompareValidator. Thinking about it, it's probably the fact that the validators prohibit the postback.

Comment: I tested using update panel, and it does the exact work I needed. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: client side methods of a validator will prevent postbacks.
You wont have to worry unless u use a custom validator.

Comment: @chead23, your next point- Validators can only be used while validating values. What if I have other controls making postback like a file uploader? I am also afraid of using update panel in every scenario.(there are known issues with update panel). I do not use them in every case since they increases viewstates/page processing time significantly, instead i do partial rendering with jquery/ajax.What if I do not want to use update panel? Do we have some script etc, to put simply on the page without using update panels? Thanks again.

Comment: A known issue with update panel- asp.net file upload doesn't works inside it.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916554/file-upload-control-not-working-inside-update-panel

Comment: @chead23, Some issues similar to the above forces me not to use update panel in the forms having file upload? How can I then prevent history to be build?

Comment: So are you using a FileUpload control? If you are this solution will still work if you put this.Page.Form.Enctype = "multipart/form-data"; in Page_Load. That's what I have done in a similar scenario to yours. Or you could use the AsyncFileUpload control in the AjaxControlToolkit.

Comment: Sorry, you also want to add  ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterPostBackControl(UploadButton); in Page_Init to register the Button used to confirm upload as a postback Control.

Comment: @chead23 ok, I will test it. Thanks. Anyways, do we have other methods rather than using update panel at all? As we know it is not always preferable to use update panels. I truly appreciate your help, I can't do +1 for now as I do not have at least 15 reputation points.

Comment: I marked as answer, I was also able to vote up. If you find any way to do this without using updatepanel please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution.
Try to add 
<% Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";%> 
above the "head" tag